# How does Python pow() function work with a negative power and a mod value

Tags: python, modulo, pow

The [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#pow) about the `pow(base, exp[, mod])` function says,
"If `mod` is present and `exp` is negative, `base` must be relatively prime to mod. In that case, `pow(inv_base, -exp, mod)` is returned, where `inv_base` is an inverse to `base` modulo `mod`."

I don't understand the line at all and also how it works. The provided example is as follows:

```
>>> pow(38, -1, mod=97)
23
>>> 23 * 38 % 97 == 1
True
```

Shouldn't it behave like (38**-1)%97 = 0.02631578947368421 ?
If I try to go from `23 * 38 % 97 == 1` to backward, I don't know what's the inverse of modulo.

Can anyone kindly give me a clear explanation of how it ended being 23? A mathematical explanation will be highly helpful.

Comment: `TypeError: pow() takes no keyword arguments` is the error i get when i run it

Comment: @CoolCloud Try a later python.

Comment: @alani Yes found that out: _Changed in version 3.8: Allow keyword arguments. Formerly, only positional arguments were supported._

Comment: You need at least Python 3.8 to run this.

Answer (score 3):

In modular arithmetic division does not have a unique answer, so we do not have a division operation. Instead you have [modular inverses](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse).

The docs are trying to explain that `pow(b, -1, mod=m)` can be used to calculate the inverse of `b`, modulo `m`. That is, finding some number `d` such that `d * b % m = 1`.

The line `23 * 38 % 97 == 1` is simply demonstrating that the answer 23, which was the result of `pow(38, -1, mod=97)`, is the correct modular inverse of 38.

The explanation in the docs seems to be assuming the reader already has some familiarity with modular arithmetic.

> Can anyone kindly give me a clear explanation of how it ended being 23? A mathematical explanation will be highly helpful.

Try running this code snippet:

```
for i in range(97): 
    s = f"{i} * 38 % 97" 
    print(s, "==", eval(s))
```

Exactly one of the lines will reveal the congruence `d * 38 % 97 == 1`. There are, of course, [smarter ways to compute the inverse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Euclidean_algorithm) but the brute force demonstration above should make it easier to understand what a modular inverse means.

Comment: That helps! Just got to know about the topic. Still trying to understand how to calculate that `d` by hand.

Comment: @SMFahim I added a brute-force example code snippet which outlines a naive approach for calculating the same (it should also reveal why the base should be relatively prime to mod).

Comment: This method helps me understand better. Don't know if it's correct, but it's working with every example. I'm writing it in detail in a new reply to the question. Please tell me whether I'm right or wrong.

Answer (score 1):

With integer arguments and `mod` specified, `pow()` does arithmetic in the "[multiplicative group of integers modulo `mod`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiplicative_group_of_integers_modulo_n)"

For example, the integers relatively prime to 8 (1, 3, 5, and 7) form a group under multiplication mod 8. The identity is 1.  Since 3*3 = 9 is congruent to 1 modulo 8, 3 is its own inverse in this group, and

```
>>> pow(3, -1, 8)
3
```

In the doc example, 23 and 38 are inverses modulo 97.

```
>>> pow(23, -1, 97)
38
>>> pow(38, -1, 97)
23
```

This isn't particularly esoteric, but rather basic tools in number theory.

Answer (score 0):

The answer from @wim and the example by @Tim Peters helps me understand what's going on in this `pow()` function. Let's take an example,

```
>>> pow(3, -1, 8)
3
```

Modulo by a number `m` must be in the `range(0,m)`. For example `14%5` must be in `range(0,5)`, hence it's 4.

So modulo `1/3 % 8` must be in the `range(8)`. But as `1/3=0.33` which is not in the range, we need a way around to find it.

`1/3 % 8` cannot be zero, as it's not divisible. So the lowest possible value is `1`. That means, we need to represent `1/3` in such a way that `x % 8 == 1` becomes True. It's obvious that `9 % 8 == 1`.
As `3(target value) * 3(base) = 9`, hence, the answer is 3(target value).

For a complex example, let's take:

```
>>> pow(38, -1, mod=97)
23
```

`1/38=0.026`. Again, need a way around. As the lowest mod should be 1, hence `x % 97 == 1`. Obviously `98 % 97 == 1`, but `98/38` is not a whole number. Next, (2*97+1) or `195 % 97 == 1`, but `195/38` is not a whole number.

In this process, (9*97+1) or `874 % 97 == 1` and `874/38=23`. So the final expression becomes:

```
23 * 38 % 97 == 1
```

Hence, the answer is 23.