# Why pow(x, y, z) not equal to pow(x, y) % z when y is -1 in Python 3.9.6?

Tags: python, math, pow

Here is my exmaple:

```py
pow(100, -1 , 321) # output 61
pow(100, -1) % 321 # output 0.01
100 ** -1 % 321 # output 0.01
```

I know that `pow(x, y, z)` should be equal to `pow(x, y) % z` or `x ** y % z`, but in my case it's not.

This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70669082/21492923) said it's because `x ** y` is too small, but in my case it's not that small at all.

Can anyone explain?

I would appreciate.

Comment: See [_How does Python pow() function work with a negative power and a mod value_](https://stackoverflow.com/q/63801527/674039)

Comment: @wim I didn't find your answer before. My bad.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A third argument to `pow()` is supported only if *all* arguments are of integer type. In that case, `pow(i, j, k)` computes the number-theoretic value of i to the j'th power in the multiplicative group of integers modulo k. You don't need this unless you need it, and then you *really* need it ;-)

A power of -1 in this context means to compute the multiplicative inverse of i modulo k, or, in other words, the integer m in range(k) such that i*m is congruent to 1 modulo k. In the example you gave,

```py
>>> 61 * 100
6100
>>> _ % 321
1
```

so 61 is the multiplicative inverse of 100 modulo 321. If a multiplicative inverse exists, it's unique (modulo k). If it doesn't exist, `pow()` raises an exception:

```
>>> pow(2, -1, 4)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: base is not invertible for the given modulus
```

Don't care about any of this? That's fine. Someday you might. In the meantime, stick to the `**` operator for raising floats to powers. 3-argument `pow()` was really designed as a convenient way to access advanced algorithms for integers.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation.I need to use this in a crypto algorithm. But my embedded machine is 32bit so the result is different. So I have to use Decimal to simulate it. Now I know it. Thank you very much.

Comment: The value of modular integer pow for given arguments should be the same regardless of the machine ;you're running on. If you have a case where it isn't, please open a different topic giving the exact inputs and outputs you're seeing.

Comment: I'm simulating on wokwi, here is the example [link](https://wokwi.com/projects/373006465140859905). Press the play button to start.

Comment: You should open a new issue with a "micropython" tag. I don't know anything about it. But "it's a bug" if it doesn't compute modular inverses correctly - assuming (I don't know) that this isn't a documented restriction in MicroPython.

Comment: Ok. But still thanks to you, I can continue on my work. Really appreciate.